# Missouri Flood, 2011--FULL POWER

Tags: alternate-history, natural-disasters

From June 2011 all the way to August, the American Midwest underwent a headline disaster--the overflow of Gavins Point Dam just outside Yankton, South Dakota, resulting in a region-wide flood.  The cause of it was a combination of high snowfall and cooler-than-average spring temperatures.  152,000 cubic feet of water went out at once, ruining the likes of towns in South Dakota, Nebraska, Iowa and Missouri.

108 lives were lost in that flood, as well as 8.41 billion dollars' worth of property and/or infrastructure.  It has also dumped the banks with silt and drowned the groves, eroding them into steep, cliff-like edges and killed most of them with root rot.

All this damage due to **a simple overflow, one that the Corps of Engineers had been criticized for not releasing the water earlier.**

In an alternate history scenario, Gavins Point didn't overflow, but **collapsed completely**, and the Missouri River returned to its former glory.  What sort of damage would we see in regards to lives, property, infrastructure and environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So living in Nebraska and living near the Missouri river I can tell you it was A LOT of water.

Towns were flooded, farms were washed away roads were destroyed...plenty of damage to lives property and infrastructure.

So...this is complicated for a couple reasons.

1. The Army Corp of Engineers release plan while somewhat flawed was also a scapegoat.  There is only so much water the system can handle.
2. The upstream impacts of the water were exacerbated by heavy rainfall along the Missouri river basin.

So all that aside...

If the dam were to completely fail the impacts would have been different, better or worse likely depends on specifics.

Locally (just south of the dam) the effects would be catastrophic.  While not densely populated the loss of life would have been greater.

This is mainly due to the fact that there would be little to no warning for the first 50 - 100 miles.

Additionally the water would have overflowed east and west more significantly than it did, the impact being greater the nearer to the dam you are.

This is mainly due to the fact that while the river wants to follow the river bed, it is also going to follow the easiest route meaning it spreads out a lot.  In short the impact of a total failure is total disaster for anything nearby.

Further downstream the impacts would probably not have been terribly different than they were.  You still have time to prepare as you go further down stream.  The water jumping the banks near the dam means the total volume of going down river is probably a little higher but not significantly.

If the dam is not repaired then you have all sorts of problems with irrigation and flow control in the following seasons.

So in short the failure would be a giant mess for anyone directly downstream of the dam and would probably end up similar for most other people.

The aftermath would have significant repercussions on regional infrastructure until the dam was replaced/repaired.

Answer (score 6):

## Not much

The Gavins Point Dam reservoir [holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavins_Point_Dam) about 600,000,000 m$^3$ of water.

The highest ever [flood level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri_River) of the Missouri River is about 21,000 m$^3$/s.

That equates to about 8 hours of discharge from the dam at the highest ever discharge level.

Thats a lot, and a reasonably bad flood, but it simply isn't enough water to do that much harm. Seen another way, the damn holds back about 492,000 acre-feet of water, enough to put 770 sq miles under a foot of water. Consider that the [floods of 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Flood_of_1993) covered 30,000 square miles.

Moral of the story: the dam's reservoir water capacity was small compared to the amount that had fallen as rain, and while the damn bursting wouldn't have made things better, it wouldn't have made them much worse.